# Using a global ruby variable inside YAML

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

Given the following YAML file:

```
---
foo: <%= $stdout %>
```

When I try to ERB this yaml file:

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(filename)).result)
```

I get the following result:

```
{"foo"=>nil}
```

Why isn't `$stdout` resolving correct?  If I put other ruby code in there, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you get when you just run ERB:

```
ERB.new("foo: <%= $stdout %>").result
```

The result is this:

```
foo: #<IO:0x0056078694db38>
```

So `foo` will be set to `nil` because `#` is the comment character in YAML.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to get foo to resolve to stdout via yaml/erb?

Comment: I don't know.  YAML is normally for storing data, not objects.  Maybe try putting the string stdout in your YAML file and convert that string to the corresponding object later.

Comment: Makes sense.  Although you can serialize/deserialize objects in YAML we probably can't do what I'm trying to do.